# RSS feed shows no entries

Tags: rss

A while back I successfully created an RSS feed on my Sitecore site. But recently I attempted to create two new feeds, following the same process, and both show no entries when I view them in the browser. All I get is some version of the XML below. The previously created feed is still working fine.

```
<rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>My Items</title>
<link>http://mysite/myitems</link>
<description>My Items</description>
<language>en</language>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Could you please add the steps you follow as well here?

Comment: I used the ones in the Sitecore guide below:

https://doc.sitecore.com/users/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/setting-up-rss-feeds.html

I should add that I'm not using the current version of Sitecore.

Comment: Turns out that the new feeds work fine in Preview mode as long as I'm logged into Sitecore in the same browser.

Comment: I tried the steps mentioned in "https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/92/sitecore-experience-platform/setting-up-rss-feeds.html", But receiving same XML as mentioned in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Statement:** After Setting up RSS Feed, if we browse or Preview, we get an XML output.

**Analysis:** I tried it out on various browser, Fortunately it worked for me in Chrome. After further investigation it was found that **RSS reader** is required   by the Browser.

**Solution:** You need to install RSS Reader Extension ([for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-feed-reader/pnjaodmkngahhkoihejjehlcdlnohgmp?hl=en)) on the browser you want the RSS Feed to be shown with descent UI.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer in two ways.

1. If I understand your question correctly, you are not getting full RSS XML but instead getting what you have shown.

Well, this could be because of how RSS is generated like your code not getting all the data, can you debug that? or share the code here?

2. To see the UI of RSS - RSS feeds are XML only, it is up to the consumer of that RSS to convert that into any UI by reading the xml nodes.
   and as far as RSS Aggregators are concern and the UI is concerned.

There are so many third-party RSS readers, Because RSS has universal format, It can be read my many readers online too.

but if you are the creator of RSS feed, there has to be consumer who can read it and show it in some proper UI.

https://www.yahoo.com/news/weather/   this is yahoo's weather UI created from the RSS feed, Something like this.

To view it in a browser, you will need RSS Aggregators or some plugins, as explained by Sunil Rana too.